# Web3 Python token sell pancakeswap

Tags: python, web3py, binance-smart-chain

Hello I am trying to sell my tokens via python web3. But sometimes I get an error "execution reverted: Pancake: K" like this.I researched this error but pancake swap tells me slippage option on their site.But I want to sell this token via python how can I add slippage tolerance ? this is my pancakeswap contract:

```
spend = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c")
balance = web3.eth.get_balance(sender_address)
humanReadable = web3.fromWei(balance, 'ether')
contract_id = web3.toChecksumAddress(contractaddress)
sellTokenContract = web3.eth.contract(contract_id, abi=sellAbi)
balance = sellTokenContract.functions.balanceOf(sender_address).call()
symbol = sellTokenContract.functions.symbol().call()
readable = web3.fromWei(balance, 'ether')
tokenValue = web3.toWei(readable, 'ether')
tokenValue2 = web3.fromWei(tokenValue, 'ether')
start = time.time()
approve = sellTokenContract.functions.approve(panRouterContractAddress, balance).buildTransaction({
        'from': sender_address,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address),
    })

signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(approve, private_key=config.private)
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print("Approved: " + web3.toHex(tx_token))
time.sleep(3)
print(f"Swapping {tokenValue2} {symbol} for BNB")


pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        tokenValue,0, 
        [contract_id,spend],
        sender_address,
        (int(time.time()) + 10000)
    ).buildTransaction({
        'from': sender_address,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei(str(gwei), 'gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address),

    })

signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key=config.private)
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(f"Sold {symbol}: " + web3.toHex(tx_token))
```

Comment: The value 0 after TokenValue should be the minimum amount willing to receive. I read this then 0 is a 100% slippage allowed and thus it should allow the transaction through. This code also gets 'transfer helper' error more often than 'K' error. Which states insufficient allowance or wallet insufficient funds. Which if 18 decimal token, that code should work. Does anyone see anything else?